# Reset auto_increment in insert into statement

Tags: mysql, innodb, sql-insert

I Have a table Invoice with: 
 id (auto_increment), 
YEAR, 
invoiceNum, 
date.

I'm working on a Insert statement.

When the YEAR change, NumInvoice has to reset.Something like check the previous year and the current, and if they are different reset it.

Until now I have:

```
insert into invoice values (null, YEAR(CURDATE()),CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),LAST_INSERT_ID()+1),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

There is a way to do this NumInvoice reset on the same insert statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You done want to reset an autoincrement column. If you do you will loose all the rows in other tables that are linked using it.

Comment: As a matter of interest what reason do you have for wanting to do this?

Comment: Sorry, it is not the id, is the numInvoice. The numInvoice has to be like auto_increment, but when year change, reset that numInvoice and start again. (EDITED)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some solution without stored routine.

```
INSERT INTO invoice (year,number,date)  SELECT  YEAR(CURDATE()),COUNT(*) + 1 ,CURDATE() FROM invoice WHERE year = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Any answer to do that with stored routines?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Write a Stored Routine to look at the latest item in the table, compare to the current date, then decide what the 'next' number should be.

It *cannot* involve an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, and it *must* be called for every new invoice.

Or you could abandon that way of generating invoice numbers.